# Get Current Row Data in Oracle Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a Oracle 10g Trigger that has a INSERT triggering event after each row and I want to base some logic in the trigger off the current row being inserted.  I would like to get the Users table flag column value being inserted and then in the trigger, use an if-then-else to do something only when flag is null. Any ideas on how to get the flag column value of the row being inserted?  My goal is to not do any of the logic in the trigger below when flag column value is null.

```
Table: USERS

Columns:
id (PK generated from a DB sequence)
.... (more columns)
flag VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) and is nullable
```

**Trigger:**

```
//goal is to not do any of the logic in the trigger below when flag is null


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DBUSER"."TI_USERS" 
  AFTER INSERT
  on Users

  for each row

declare numrows INTEGER;
begin
    select count(*) into numrows
      from Customer
      where
        /* %JoinFKPK(:%New,Customer," = "," and") */
        :new.Customer_Key = Customer.Customer_Key;
    if (
      /* %NotnullFK(:%New," is not null and") */

      numrows = 0
    )
    then
      raise_application_error(
        -20002,
        'Cannot INSERT Users because Customer does not exist.'
      );
    end if;



end;
ALTER TRIGGER "SIMPLEX"."TI_USERS" ENABLE
```

Comment: This logic should be the work of a foreign key, not a trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DBUSER"."TI_USERS" 
  AFTER INSERT
  on Users

  for each row

declare numrows INTEGER;
begin

IF ( :new.flag IS NOT NULL ) Then

    select count(*) into numrows
      from Customer
      where
        /* %JoinFKPK(:%New,Customer," = "," and") */
        :new.Customer_Key = Customer.Customer_Key;
    if (
      /* %NotnullFK(:%New," is not null and") */

      numrows = 0
    )
    then
      raise_application_error(
        -20002,
        'Cannot INSERT Users because Customer does not exist.'
      );
    end if;

end if;

end;
ALTER TRIGGER "SIMPLEX"."TI_USERS" ENABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

surround the entire block with `if :new.flag is not null then  ...   end if;`